# Dafny unexpected assertion violation

Tags: dafny

Why Dafny is not able to prove this?

```
method Main() {

assert forall f:map<string,int>, x:string, v:int :: x in f.Keys  ==>  f.Values- 
{f[x]} + {v} == (f[x:=v]).Values;

}
```

Comment: Even this: `assert v in (f[x:=v]).Values;`.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is not true if `f` contains duplicate values. For example, consider the map

```
var f := map[1 := 0, 2 := 0];
```

which satisfies

```
assert f.Values == {0};
```

Now make an updated map by setting the key 1 to have value 7,

```
var f' := f[1 := 7];
```

Then `f'[1] == 7` and `f'[2] == 0`, so `f'` satisfies

```
assert f'.Values == {0, 7};
```

but your assertion would imply `f'.Values == {0}`, which is false.

---

For the second question you asked in a comment, the assertion is true, but Dafny cannot prove it because of a triggering problem. You can convince Dafny to prove it by saying

```
var f' := f[x:=v];          // give updated map a name for convenience
assert f'[x] in f'.Values;  // triggers axiom about .Values
assert v in f'.Values;      // now this verifies
```

For more information about triggers, see the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/wiki/FAQ). You may also be interested to read the [axiomatic definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Binaries/DafnyPrelude.bpl#L1141-L1145) for the `.Values` primitive operation.

Comment: Ups, right, my false assertion is a good example of taking non-care in apparently easy properties. Thanks. I wonder if it makes sense to have the possibility of a .Values-like attribute that gives a multiset, instead of a set, of Values to enable the kind of reasoning in my false assertion. Of course, it can be user-defined.